# How to save Jboss messages from queue

Tags: linux, jboss, queue, wildfly, message

how can I save alle messages from jboss queue to filesystem?
I have for example such construct:

```
/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=myQueue:read-messages()
```

Is it possible to set write-messages() or so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default, ActiveMQ logs are saved in `${jboss.server.data.dir}/activemq/journal` (usually `wildfly/data/activemq/journal`). [You can change this](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Admin_Guide.html#Mesaging_AIO_-_NIO_for_messaging_journal) to use a JDBC store as well.